# Xcode bundle identifier needs to be unique message

Tags: xcode, xcode8

```
Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "com.example.hello" cannot be registered to your development team. 
Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.
```

This is the message that I get within Xcode when I select my own user account under *Signing>Team "Pieter (Personal Team)"*. I'm trying to build a sample application (Cordova).

If I change the bundle ID I can get rid of the error, but I don't accept that workaround as a solution. I need to be able to build a sample project with its own bundle ID.

Comment: Changing the bundle id isn't a workaround, it's the solution.  The bundle id has to be unique so if the one you pick is already being used the only thing you can do is change it.

Comment: Unique compared to what? Is com.example.hello registered with Apple?

Comment: @Pieter com.example.* is registered from someone else

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was selecting the wrong Dev Team while exporting the archive:

[image: Development team]

Comment: Could you add some more context about where this screen is located, and how you pick the correct one?  Thanks

Comment: @NewAlexandria this screen occurs when you want to export an archived app. In my case, I used the Save to Ad Hoc Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The app Id must match with your own domain, for example:

[image]

You can get more information about this here: [App ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AppID.html)

Comment: Thank you. I am not enrolled in a developer program, so I don't think I can register my own (wildcard) bundle ID?

Comment: Yes you can register your own bundle id

Comment: Sign in to Xcode with your Apple ID, then set your Bundle Identifier to your project

Comment: FYI The error I receive is not because the bundle ID is not registered to my name, because if I change any part of it it is accepted. For example I can change it to world.example.hello or com.example.pj and it can be built...